# Can you take moxifloxacin and doxycycline at the same time?

Tags: bacteria, antibiotics

For antibiotic resistant bacteria that is handled by two rounds of antibiotics, why are the two prescribed sequentially rather than at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the very specific pair of antibiotics you have asked about, I will assume that your hypothetical senario is regarding [*Mycobacterium genitalium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycoplasma_genitalium) infection.

The US Centers for Disease Control and prevention [recommends](https://www.cdc.gov/std/treatment-guidelines/mycoplasmagenitalium.htm) the following as a potential treatment regimen:

> Doxycycline 100 mg orally 2 times/day for 7 days followed by moxifloxacin 400 mg orally once daily for 7 days

The CDC goes on to note:

> As part of this approach, doxycycline is provided as initial empiric therapy, which reduces the organism load and facilitates organism clearance

A paper by Read and colleagues (2019. PMCID [6355821](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6355821/)) concurs:

> Because several studies have shown that *M. genitalium* infections with lower loads were more likely to be cured, it may be that doxycycline lowered bacterial load, rendering *M. genitalium* more susceptible to a subsequent macrolide [11, 13, 20].

###### Thus, the two treatments are consecutive because the first (doxycycline) decreases the number of bacteria which can be better handled by the body during the second treatment.

I have not been able to find any specific trials of using the two drugs together concurrently, but [online drug interaction checkers](https://www.drugs.com/interactions-check.php?drug_list=1659-0,940-0) do not indicate any conflicts between doxycycline and moxifloxacin.